# Getting arguments of a called Typemock mocked method

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, typemock

I am a keen user of RhinoMocks developing from a TDD and AAA perspective with NUnit and ReSharper. I am changing jobs and the team I am moving to uses TypeMock so I want to hit the ground running... and I have run into a problem. How can I get the arguments for a called method on a mock object. When using RhinoMocks I use:

```
mockObject.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(x => x.MethodIWantToGetParametersFrom(null))
```

Which returns a IList of type object array. Great! I go and get what I want and process it how I wish. Now using the AAA syntax of TypeMock I cannot seem to work out a way to do this... Could anyone shed some light on this please? Should I be doing it differently?

Thanks for reading and I look forward to your responses!

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DoInstead():

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(()=>x.MethodIWantToGetParametersFrom).DoInstead(context => Console.WriteLine(context.Parameters[0].ToString())
```

You get a Context object that contains the param values.

you can also implement a method with the same name on your own class, and swap calls from the faked object to that method:

```
 class MyOwnClass
    {
    void MethodIWantTOGetParametersFrom(string s){
Console.WriteLine(s);
} //this is NOT the real method
    }

    //in test:
    MyOwnClass own = new MyOwnClass();
    Isolate.Swap.CallsOn(realClassInstance).WithCallsTo(own); //only methods that are implemented in the OwnCalss will be redirected. others will be called on the original instance.
```